# And easy to convert an audio file into a video?

Tags: video, openshot

I am involved in producing a podcast which I upload to LinkedIn.

Typically, I design covert art for 1080p and add that and the audio as tracks in OpenShot and then convert to a video format.

Is there an easier or CLI-based way to do this?

Comment: Does this help: https://superuser.com/questions/1041816/combine-one-image-one-audio-file-to-make-one-video-using-ffmpeg ?

Comment: Yes! Command executing now. Thank you so much!